# I can't log back in my Ubuntu account after logging out (I have a cromebook acer C720)

Tags: programming

I have installed ubuntu on my crome book (acer C720) and when I was updating something I dicided to log out (I usually hit shut down and I would be able to get back in) and now I can't get back in.

Comment: does it log you in automatically on boot?

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/

Comment: `now I can't get back in.` What is the problem? Does your username and password not work, does it not boot, login screen not showing, etc...